# Trying to get Apache Spark working with IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to get Apache Spark working with IntelliJ. I have created an SBT project in IntelliJ and done the following:
1. Gone to File -> Project Structure -> Libraries
2. Clicked the '+' in the middle section, clicked Maven, clicked Download Library from Maven Repository, typed text 'spark-core' and org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0, which is the latest version of Spark available
I downloaded the jar files and the source code into ./lib in the project folder
3. The Spark library is now showing in the list of libraries
4. Then I right-clicked on org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0 and clicked Add to Project and Add to Modules
Now when I click on Modules on the left, and then my main project folder, and then Dependencies tab on the right I can see the external library as a Maven library, but after clicking Apply, re-building the project and re-starting IntelliJ, it will not show as an external library in the project. Therefore I can't access the Spark API commands. 
What am I doing wrong please? I've looked at all the documentation on IntelliJ and a hundred other sources but can't find the answer.

Also, do I also need to include the following text in the build.SBT file, as well as specifying Apache Spark as an external library dependency? I assume that I need to EITHER include the code in the build.SBT file, OR add Spark as an external dependency manually, but not both.
I included this code in my build.SBT file:

```
name := "Spark_example"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

val sparkVersion = "2.0.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)
```

I get an error: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.2.0: not found

Please help! Thanks

Comment: `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"` should work.

Comment: Thanks, it does, but I get some warnings about incompatibility with Spark v2.0.0, so I tried 2.2.0 instead and that seems to deal with some of them but not all

Comment: it's always recommended to use dependency management tools(SBT, Maven, Gradle) to add external jars with scope(compile/test/provided etc).

Comment: Thank you very much mrsrinivas!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spark does not have builds for Scala version 2.12.x. So set the Scala version to **2.11.x**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.0.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name := "Test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91" % "runtime"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive-thriftserver" % "2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91" % "provided"
```